# Looking for a Macro code to update corresponding columns

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I have a column which has single and multiple languages such as "English", "French", "Russian", "English or Dutch", "French & English".

My query is I would like to write macro code where if we have single language (English) then it should be updated as "Single" and "Multiple" for multiple language ("English or French" , "English & French"). I tried recording a macro but no luck as we keep on getting new languages on a regular basis.

[image]

Comment: This can be done with formulas, if you don't have any languages like Western Punjabi or something you can just look for spaces and if it exists then it is multiple.

Comment: Are separators between languages standardized?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this formula:

`=IF(AND(ISERROR(FIND("&", B1) > 0), ISERROR(FIND("OR", B1) > 0)), "Single", "Multiple")`